# Is there a way to perform subquery on MongoDB using collection.aggregate() and PHP Driver?

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am migrating a `MySQL` table which has 50 million+ `rows` and 40 `columns` to a `MongoDB` database. This table data is shown on a `html` `table` and every column is searchable and sortable. To get a better performance on `MySQL` queries I make a `subselect` from this table filtering by a column named `company_id` and limiting it to 50k rows and ordering by `id` and `date` to get the last 50k rows that belongs to that company, and then from this `subselect` I perform the other filtering and ordering logics sent by frontend. Basically this is how the `MySQL` Query looks like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
            SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4 -- other fields
              FROM myTable
             WHERE company_id = 50
             ORDER BY id DESC, dateField desc
             LIMIT 50000
         ) AS tb
 WHERE tb.field1 = 'A filter'
   AND tb.field2 = 'Another filter'
 -- more and more filters
 ORDER BY tb.FIELD3
```

There is any way to do something like that on a `MongoDb` `table` using `db.collection.aggregate()` and `Mongo` `PHP` Driver?

Comment: You may try out the `MongoCollection::aggregate`. Take a look at the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php)